# Jquery Mobile "pageinit" not firing

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, geolocation

Im trying to use the Geolocation API with Jquery Mobile. Everything works fine if i browse directly to my page from the browser.

But, if i navigate to it from another page, it does not load.

Also, if i remove the line of code with the "pageinit" command, i get the same issue/error but if i refresh the page it will load.

I know it has something to do with the way the DOM is handled through AJAX but i cant seem to get it to work the way it should/i want it to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Location</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="geoPage">


        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#geoPage").live("pageinit", function() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
                } else {
                    error('Geolocation not supported');
                }
            });

            function success(position) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var mapcanvas = $('#mapcanvas');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapcanvas[0], myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng, 
                map: map, 
                title:"I am here!"
            });


            //alert(latlng);


            }


            function error(msg) {
                var errMsg = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "Geolocation failed";
                $('#msg').html(errMsg);
            }


            $("#continue7").click(function(e){


                $.mobile.changePage( "extension.htm", { transition: "slide"} );


            });
        </script>


        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Location</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="msg"></div>
            <div id="mapcanvas" style="height: 250px; width:250px;"></div>
            <input id="continue7" type="button" value="Conintue" />



        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're working with an alpha version which was released a pretty long time ago. Update your dependencies to the latest jQM 1.1.0 release and  jQuery 1.6/1.7!

Comment: Check this post. It worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848352/phonegap-jquery-mobile-on-android-multiple-html-pages-javascript-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) for how to handle the pageinit event is slightly different than your approach -- at least the section of the documentation I was looking at. Their suggestion is that you would code it like this:

```
$( document ).delegate("#geoPage", "pageinit", function() {
    // Handle it
}
```

The documentation sounded like you have placed your function in the best location if you want to bind this way.

**Edit**:

Notably, [this particular page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) describes binding exactly as you have shown (but adds `event` into the anonymous function which I don't think should affect your situation). This leads me to believe that you might have a javascript error in your Developer Tools Console when you navigate from another page and the page gives off an appearance of 'not working'. Be sure to check for that in your Developer Tool of choice.

**Edit**:

The solution for you is that you need to include your google maps javascript 'include' somewhere within the `data-role='page'` element. Jquerymobile is going to ignore everything outside of that every time it does an AJAX page load. Alternatively, you could turn all links into this page into `data-ajax="false"`.

Include the following line *inside* of your data-role="page" or include it in the html `<head>` for every page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Be sure to really read and let the original link sink in. Best practice is that you have the same `<head>` element for every page and include it rather than copy-paste it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using your suggested code i get the exact same behavior. But, i just tried to debug my javascript with chrome and it says google is not defined. But it should be defined from the script in the head. I aslo tried to move that script into my page and i get the same error...

Comment: I fixed it. Once i got the error, i realized it wasnt loading my script on page transition. So, i moved the include for the API to my index file. That way it will be loaded with the DOM. And i can access it later. Im not sure if this is the way i should do this, but it works. Please advise if this is a frowned upon method. Also, awarded your answer as my solution since you got my brain spinning in the right direction.

Comment: In general, you should have the same `<html><head></head>` segment in every page. That is basically what jquerymobile is going to assume. Those segments of the page are only going to get loaded once -- whichever page the user accesses first. So if there are page-specific elements that need to be included on  just one page (like `google`, here) be sure to include it _inside_ the `data-role="page"`. Be sure to read the first documentation link for the best practice. Thanks

Comment: @user1289451; updated my answer to reflect the situation you ran into. Keep that Developer Tools open while you go; it will be a blessing!

Comment: How do i include the head in every page? I havent been able to find a suitable method of doing this. I know it can be done for Javascript but what about the HTML elements? Ive read of a workaround using the .write function of Javascript, but that seemed odd to me to have to do that...

Comment: @user1289451, that depends on what language you are working with. I'm most familiar with `.php` pages which makes it very easy to include other files. Is that a possibility for you? Then you could simply execute `include("headerFile.php");`