# PhoneGap and JQM linking pages

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on android webapp I am using phoneGap v2.9.0 and JQM V1.3.1
In in the index.html page the initilaziation of both framework is successful I was able to use 
JQM after the

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

When linking to an external page but in the same project lets say contact.html the initilazition of both frameworks failed and there is no ability to use any of them 
I checked the JQM documentation concerning linking external pages 
[JQM documentation for linking pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

they explained that the linking process in JQM is done via an Ajax request If the Ajax request is successful, the new page content is added to the DOM 
does that mean that all included scripts in contact.html is loaded to the index page ? which means that I might have a duplication of each library and script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this situation you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. It uses ajax to load other pages.

First page is loaded normally. Its **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** is loaded into the **`DOM`**, and they are there to await other content. When second page is loaded, **only** its **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**.

That's why your button is show successfully but click event is not working. Same click event whose parent **`HEAD`** was disregarded during the page transition.

Here's an official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Unfortunately you are not going to find this described in their documentation. Ether they think this is a common knowledge or they forgot to describe this like my other topics. (jQuery Mobile documentation is big but lacking many things).

1. Put all of your JavaScript into a first HTML/ASP file
2. Move your JavaScript into `<body>`; to be more precise, move it into a `<div>` with `data-role="page"`. As I already pointed out, this is the only part of a page that is going to be loaded.
3. Use `rel="external"` when switching between pages because it will trigger a full page refresh. Basically, you jQuery mobile that the page will act as a normal web application.

#### Edit:

Working examples can be found in this blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**, to be transparent it is my blog.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation , so only the body of the second page is loaded and not the head ! so any script included in the head will not work. bu I am not sure how much it is recommended to append the js script after the div I will test it in all cases I've found another solution is to disable to ajax request of jqm and perform a normal http request by adding the attribute  data-ajax="false" [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848352/phonegap-jquery-mobile-on-android-multiple-html-pages-javascript-not-working]

Comment: data-ajax="false" works as well, just like rel="external". I forgot to mention, this handling is even more restrictive. If you have more then one page inside a second HTML only first page is going to be loaded. Everything other page is going to be discarded, just like a HEAD. Also I have added a link to my blog post where working examples / solutions can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Childbrowser plugin* or

```
window.location.href="";
```