# jQuery Mobile create a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to start with jQuery Mobile but I'm stuck when I'm trying to create a left panel with an overlay slide. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>- test-</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="panel" id="testPanel" data-theme="e" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
    <h3>Default panel options</h3>
    <p>This panel has all the default options: positioned on the left with the reveal display mode. The panel markup is <em>before</em> the header, content and footer in the source order.</p>
    <p>To close, click off the panel, swipe left or right, hit the Esc key, or use the button below:</p>
</div>
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <a href="#testPanel" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Contact</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Copyright 2013 - All Rights Reserved -</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work, when I'm clicking on my link button I have this message "Error loading page" and the content of my panel is already shown in the page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using outdated versions of both `jQuery` and `jQuery Mobile` frameworks. I would suggest updating to the latest release versions.

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ghtz/) with your same markup using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Sliding panels were introduced in JQM 1.3 version. So it won't work for other versions. USe jQuery 1.7.2- 1.9.1 for JQM 1.3

See the blog post for more details : http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/

Answer (score 1):

If this is not your index page then you are most probably navigate to it through an `<a href="yourpage.html>Page</a>` in this case jquery uses Ajax request to navigate from one page to another the ajax request does not load the whole content of your page , it only loads the content of the `<body>` tag i.e any scripts that you are writing inside the `<head>` tag will not be loaded thus the page will not work properly and you will face error 
to solve this you need to use `data-ajax="false"` inside the `<a>` attribute to prevent jquery mobile to use Ajax call to load your page.

if it is your index page then please past the js code so we can check it
in all cases check these link
[for loading jqm pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667420/javascript-not-working-in-second-html-file-in-phonegap-jquery-mobile) and this link [problem of ajax call in jqm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418679/phonegap-and-jqm-linking-pages)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, this is really useful for a beginner like me! cheers ;D